# Ansible to consolidate service status on multiple servers

Tags: ansible

Below playbook works where inventory groups has multiple servers and to check the status of each service and display its status on console.

Problem is, I wanted to consolidate the status of each service on every server and send in an email, but it seems array (uistatus_app, uistatus_status, uistatus_print) gets re-initiated for each server run.

Is there any way where I can store the status in the global variable of each run and display?

for example:

server1: nginx is active

server1: PHP is active

server2: nginx is active

server2: PHP is unknown

Thanks.

```yaml
- name: checking services
  shell: 'systemctl is-active {{item}}'
  with_items:
    - nginx
    - php74-php-fpm
  failed_when: false
  register: uistatus
  when: 'inventory_hostname in groups[''stg-ui]'
- name: get ui status in arrray
  set_fact:
    uistatus_app: '{{uistatus_app}}+[ ''{{item.item}}'']'
    uistatus_status: '{{uistatus_app}}+[ ''{{item.stdout}}'']'
  with_items: '{{ uistatus.results }}'
  when: 'inventory_hostname in groups[''stg-ui]'
- name: consolidate
  set_fact:
    uistatus_print: '{{uistatus_print}}+{{inventory_hostname}}: {{item[0]}} is item[1]}}]'
  loop: '{{ query(''together'',uistatus_app, uistatus.status }}'
  when: 'inventory_hostname in groups[''stg-ui]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the variable with the list of the statuses in each host, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: checking services
      command: "echo {{ item }} is active"
      loop:
        - nginx
        - php74-php-fpm
      failed_when: False
      register: uistatus
      when: inventory_hostname in groups.stg_ui
    - set_fact:
        my_services: "{{ uistatus.results|default([])|
                         map(attribute='stdout')|
                         list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_services
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [server1] => 
  my_services:
  - nginx is active
  - php74-php-fpm is active
ok: [server2] => 
  my_services:
  - nginx is active
  - php74-php-fpm is active
```

Then *run_once*, *extract* the lists and create the dictionary *all_services*, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        all_services: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|zip(stats)) }}"
      vars:
        stats: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                   map('extract', hostvars, 'my_services')|
                   list }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: all_services
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [server1] => 
  all_services:
    server1:
    - nginx is active
    - php74-php-fpm is active
    server2:
    - nginx is active
    - php74-php-fpm is active
```

The dictionary is available to all hosts in the playbook.

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir. Very much appreciated.